# Change the Drawable when a different user sends a message

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a Chat with Bubbles speechs, I'm getting the messages from a Json file.

Now I'm trying to change the color from the Bubble when a specific user talks.

I'm using Java to get the message and the Id from the user that sent the message, from my Json file.

I created a "Session" to get the Id from the logged in user and I am comparing this Id to the Id from the message sender, to check wish bubble i will use.

To do that, i created a String called position. If the ID from the logged in user is equal to the Id from the opened session, the bubble changes the color, and goes to the right.

I created an adapter to receive the message and insert the bubble there. I'm checking which user sent the message, calling the position variable.

My problem is that all the bubbles are being changed, but with a single color. And i would like to change the bubble from specific messages. When the logged in user talks, it must show a different bubble.

How can i Do that?

**Variables**

```
private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "reply";
private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
```

**Getting Data**

```
 //Calling session from logged in user

            NewSession app = (NewSession) getApplication();
            String logid = app.getLogid();

...

JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                    // Getting JSON Array node
                    contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_CONTACTS);

                    // looping through All Contacts
                    for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                        String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                        String message = c.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                        String position = "";

                        if(username == logid){
                        position = "right";
                        }else{
                        position = "left";
                        }

                       HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();

                      // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                      contact.put(TAG_ID, id);
                      contact.put(TAG_MESSAGE, message);
```

**Adapter**

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

      View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);


      TextView message = (TextView) v.getTag();

      if(message == null){
         message = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.msg);
          v.setTag(message);
      }

     String url = (String) ((Map)getItem(position)).get(TAG_POSITION);

     message.setBackgroundResource(url == "left" ? R.drawable.bubble_green : R.drawable.bubble_yellow);

      return v;
   }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Don't compare Strings with s1 == s2, you should use s1.equals(s2)

Comment: Yeaa, thanks a lot man, now is working fine! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't compare Strings with
  s1 == s2
you should use
  s1.equals(s2)

Answer (score 0):

You're using the `==` (reference) comparison instead of `String#equals()` comparison in your adapter.

Try this:

```
     message.setBackgroundResource("left".equalsIgnoreCase(url) ? R.drawable.bubble_green : R.drawable.bubble_yellow);
```